# Check when program started in Windows

Tags: windows, task-manager

Is there any way to check when the program has started in Windows XP Pro? I tried with task manager I couldn't see when program has started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from Sysinternals/Microsoft as a task manager replacement.  It includes start time and much more.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to check when the
>   program has started in Windows XP Pro?

**[Anvir Task Manager](http://www.anvir.com/download.htm)** will show this detail, when you hover over a program/service.

[image]

*A free and portable version is available.*